# Why is my keybinding not working?

Tags: key-bindings

I am trying to customize my settings on Paredit. Instead of using the default `C-right` and `C-left`, I would like to do `C-<` and `C->`. I tried with this code inside my init file:

```
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C->>") 'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-<>")  'paredit-forward-barf-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") nil)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>")  nil)))
```

Apparently, it works with order bindings, such as "<C-)>". Unfortunately, it **does not** work with "C->>". I guess the consecutive ">>" are causing problems.

How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just do `(kbd "C->")` - don't use the angle brackets here. I'm assuming you are using GUI emacs, not terminal emacs - correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @NickD, I was able to reach the solution. Just to be clear for other users, I will post it here:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C->") 'paredit-forward-slurp-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-<") 'paredit-forward-barf-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-M-<") 'paredit-backward-slurp-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "C-M->") 'paredit-backward-barf-sexp)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-right>") nil)
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "<C-left>") nil)))
```